# How many open sets are needed to separate all pairs of disjoint closed sets?

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

Let $\mathscr{U}$ be a collection of open subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ which separates closed sets. That is, for every pair of disjoint closed sets $A,B \subset \mathbb{R}$, there exist disjoint $U,V \in \mathscr{U}$ such that $A \subset U$ and $B \subset V$. Is it obvious that $\mathscr{U}$ needs to have $\mathfrak{c}$ elements?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Every subset of $\mathbb Z$ is closed. Let as assign to each $A\subseteq\mathbb Z$ disjoint open sets $U_A$, $U_{\mathbb Z\setminus A}$ such that $A\subseteq U_A$ and $\mathbb Z\setminus A\subseteq U_{\mathbb Z\setminus A}$. Then the map $A\mapsto U_A$ is an injective map from $\mathcal P(\mathbb Z)$ to $\mathscr U$.

Proof of injectivity: Let $B\ne A$, w.l.o.g $B\subsetneqq A$. Let  $a\in A\setminus B$. Then $a\in U_A$, since $a\in A$. Also $a\in\mathbb Z\setminus B$ implies $a\notin U_B$. Thus $U_A\ne U_B$.

---

EDIT: The above answers the original question. I just want to add some thoughts what can change if we work with a compact subspace of $\mathbb R$ instead of the whole real line.

So let us ask the same question about $[0,1]$ instead of $\mathbb R$. Since $[0,1]$ is compact, we cannot find infinite closed discrete subspace in it, so the above trick will not work.

We have a countable basis $\mathcal B=\{(p,q)\cap[0,1]; p<q, p,q\in\mathbb Q\}$ for this space. Using compactness we can show that any two closed subsets can be separated by sets $U$, $V$ such that each of them is a *finite intersection of finite unions* or a *finite union of finite intersections* of basic sets from $\mathcal B$. (See bellow.)  I.e., every separating set is of the form $\bigcap_{i=1}^k \bigcup_{j=1}^l B_{ij}$ or of the form $\bigcup_{i=1}^k \bigcap_{j=1}^l B_{ij}$, where each $B_{ij}$ is in $\mathcal B$. The system $\mathscr U$ consisting of all such sets is countable system of open sets. (The set of all finite sequences of element of given countable set is again countable.) So in this space, a set of size $\aleph_0$ is sufficient.

Basically the same proof would work in any second countable compact space.

---

We know that any two points can be separated by basic sets from $\mathcal B$. Suppose we are given two disjoint closed sets $A$ and $B$. Closed subsets of compact space are compact.

We can show that for any $x\notin A$ there exist sets $U_x$ and $V_x$ such that:

- $A\subseteq U_x$, $x\in V_x$ and $U_x\cap V_x = \emptyset$ (i.e., these sets separate $U$, $V$)
- $U_x$ is a finite union of sets from $\mathcal B$
- $V_x$ is a finite intersection of sets from $\mathcal B$

The proof of this fact is exactly the same as in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83355/how-to-prove-that-a-compact-set-in-a-hausdorff-topological-space-is-closed/83357#83357) with the only exception that we have to work with basic sets only.

Now we can repeat basically the same argument again. For every $b\in B$  we have sets $U_b$, $V_b$ with the above properties. Now as $V_b$ is an open cover of $B$, thus there exists finite subcover $\{V_b; b\in F\}$. The sets $U:=\bigcap_{b\in F} U_b$ and $V:=\bigcup_{b\in F} V_b$ separate $A$ and $B$ and they belong to the family $\mathscr U$ described above.

Comment: Perfect, thank you Martin.