# Proof for Urysohn's lemma.

Tags: general-topology

I've read the proof of Urysohn's lemma from JAMES R. MUNKRES' text.I got it upto very extent.But,I'm not getting intuition for this proof.I liked the proof [Proving that a compact subset of a Hausdorff space is closed](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1329760/proving-that-a-compact-subset-of-a-hausdorff-space-is-closed?lq=1) by Brian M.Scott.I want someone to help me in getting the proof for Urysohn's lemma in  the similar fashion.

Thank You!!

Comment: But the intuition part of that lemma is not that hard, I suppose: The idea is to construct a continuous functoin $\to[0,1]$ as a limit of finer and finer staircase functions. The ability needed to refine a staircase function is precisely the condition in the premise of the lemma.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/341019/4280 has an explanation by Brian as well. Does it help?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1106917/4280 is also helpful.