# connected components of domain without preimage of critical values

Tags: differential-topology, singularity, inverse-function-theorem

Let $f:M \to N$ be a differentiable map between two connected compact manifolds both of dimension $n\ge 2$ (I think i know the answer to my question if $n=1$). Let us assume that both $M$ and $N$ are connected and the image of $f$ is dense in $N$. So we know that preimage of a regular value is finite. Consider the regular points in $M$ and take the connected components of it. Let $A\subset M$ be such a component and suppose furthermore that that there are two different points $x,y\in A$ such that $f(x)=f(y)$. I have a complicated example ($n=2$) where this setup is possible. Let $U$ be a largest neighbourhood of $x$ in $A$ such that $f|U$ is injective (so if there is any $U'\supset U$ such that $f|U'$ is diffeomorphic to $f(U')$ then $U=U'$).

My questions is:

1. Is it true that the boundary of this largest neighbourhood $U'$ of $x$ will necessarily contain a point $x'$ in $A$ such that $f(x')$ is a critical value?
2. Is it true that the preimage of the critical value "separates" two points with the same image, i.e. if I consider $M$ without the preimage of the critical values then $f$ restricted to a connected component of this set is injective?

I would appreciate a counterexample or rough proof.

**Edit1**: Apparently I [asked a question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2774744/should-the-points-in-the-fiber-lie-in-different-connected-component?rq=1) some years ago that is related to this question and the answer to that question would also answer my question here (both 1. and 2. are not necessarily true).

**Edit2**: Actually the example that was given to me two years ago was when $M$ is not compact and in my question I assumed $M$ is compact. I wonder if someone can give me an example when $M$ is the torus (so $n=2$).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to have more conditions for this work. Here is an example when $M$ is compact and $n=2$ such that neither 1. nor 2. is true:

Take $M$ to be the unit sphere $S^2$ and $N$ to be the projecitve plane. We now take $f$ to be the natural map sending antipodal points of $S^2$ to the same point in the projective plane (represented by one of these points). This map is smooth and yet $2:1$.