# Intersection of two compact subsets in a Hausdorff space

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Prove that if $K$ and $L$ are compact subsets of a Hausdorff space $X$, then $K \cap L$ is a compact subset of $X$.

I understand that since $K$ and $L$ are compact subsets, they each have finite coverings.  Do I have to show that the intersection of $2$ finite coverings is a compact subset?

Comment: Hint:  $K$ and $L$ must be closed sets and $K \cap L \subseteq K$.

Answer (score 1):

> **Theorem**:Any compact subset of a Hausdorff space is closed.

You can find a proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83355/how-to-prove-that-a-compact-set-in-a-hausdorff-topological-space-is-closed).

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be an open cover of  $K \cap L$. Since $K$ and $L$ are closed sets ,$K \cap L$ is also closed. So  ${(K \cap L)}^C$ is open. Then $\mathcal{B}=\mathcal{A}\cup {(K \cap L)}^C$ is an open cover of  $K$(and $L$). Since $K$ is compact,$\mathcal{B}$ has a finite subcover,say,$\{A_1,A_2,\ldots,A_n,{(K \cap L)}^C\}$. So $\{A_1,A_2,\ldots,A_n\}$ is a finite subcover of $\mathcal{A}$ that covers $K \cap L$. Hence, $K \cap L$ is compact.

Comment: Why don't you have 2 cases to account for whether or not $(K\cap L)^C$ is included in the finite subcover?

Comment: @JackBauer Even if $(K\cap L)^C $ is not included in the finite subcover, still the union of that subcover and $(K\cap L)^C $ will cover $K$, right? So basically I was trying to incorporate the two cases into one by taking the above mentioned subcover. If there is any mistake , please let me know.

Comment: I didn't analyze anymore, but if you did "incorporate the two cases", then that's brilliant.