# Rudin's functional analysis theorem 3.21.

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-explanation, topological-vector-spaces, weak-topology

Small proof of

> Suppose $X$ is a topological vector space on which $X^*$ separates points. Suppose $A$ and $B$ are disjoint, nonempty, compact, convex sets in $X$. Then there exits $\Lambda \in X^*$ such that
>   $$
> \sup_{x \in A} \text{Re}\; \Lambda x < \inf_{y \in B} \text{Re}\; \Lambda y
> $$

Proof below:

> Let $X_w$ be $X$ with its topology. The sets $A$ and $B$ area clearly compact in $X_w$. They're also closed in $X_w$ (because $X_w$ is a Hausdorff space).

Why exactly are $A$ and $B$ closed? How does it follow from the fact that $X_w$ is Hausdorff?

> Since $X_w$ is locally convex...

Why is $X_w$ locally convex? Is it possible it follows from the fact that every weak neighborhood contains sets of the form

$$
V = \left\{ x : |\Lambda_i x | < r_i \;,\; 1 \leq i \leq n\right\}
$$

Which would form a local base, and since such sets are convex then we have a locally convex space?

> ... (b) of theorem 3.4. can be applied to $X_w$ in place of $X$; it gives us a $\Lambda \in (X_w)^*$ that satisfies (1). But we saw in section 3.11 (as consequence of theorem 3.10) that $(X_w)^* = X^*$.

Comment: This might help: http://mathonline.wikidot.com/compact-sets-in-hausdorff-topological-spaces

Answer (score 1):

To answer your two questions:

1. It is a fact from general topology that compact subsets of Hausdorff spaces are closed (see for instance: [this stack exchange question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83355/how-to-prove-that-a-compact-set-in-a-hausdorff-topological-space-is-closed)).
2. Theorem 3.10 in Functional Analysis states that if $X$ is a topological vector space and $X'$ is a separating family of linear functionals on $X$, then the topology induced by $X'$ on $X$ is locally convex. Since in the hypothesis to this theorem $X^*$ separates points, the weak topology it induces is thus locally convex.

Comment: I was just reading through theorem 3.10 again.