# Locally compact preregular spaces are completely regular

Tags: general-topology

First some definitions:

> A space is called [locally compact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_compact_space) if each point has at least one compact nbhd.
>
> Two points $a$ and $b$ are called [topologically distinguishable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_indistinguishability) if there is some open set containing $a$ and not $b$, or containing $b$ and not $a$.  For example, in a $T_0$ space any two points are topologically distinguishable.
>
> A space is called [preregular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preregular_space) (or $R_1$) if any two topologically distinguishable points are separated by disjoint nbhds. It's a generalization of both Hausdorff spaces and regular spaces.

It is a well-known result that every locally compact Hausdorff space is completely regular.  Now [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_compact_space) as well [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3813191/52912) from Tyrone mention that the same holds if Hausdorff is replaced by regular, or even more generally by preregular.

> **Theorem**: Every locally compact preregular space is completely regular.

Can anyone provide a proof?

Comment: You should define "topologically distinguishable".

Comment: Does completely regular include Hausdorff?

Comment: @PaulFrost I am using the definition of completely regular from wikipedia or Willard for example (points and closed sets can be separated by a function), which does not include Hausdorff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the equivalence relation on your space, say we call it $X$, according to which $x R y$ iff $x$ and $y$ are indistinguishable, and let $Y=X/R$.

Observe that every open subset of $X$ is saturated under $R$, almost by definition!   Therefore the quotient map $q:X\to Y$ is an open map.

It then follows that $Y$ is locally compact.  Moreover  the preregular hypothesis now easily implies that $Y$ is Hausdorff.

If $C$ is a closed subset of $X$, and $x\in X\setminus C$, then $q(C)$ is closed and $q(x)\notin q(C)$.

The classical result applied to $Y$ now provides a function $f:Y\to[0,1]$ such that $f(q(x))=1$, and $f=0$ on $q(C)$.

The composition $f\circ q$ now satisfies the desired properties.

Comment: How do you like it now?

Comment: Very good, thank you.

Comment: Glad to be able to help.  Also, thanks for an interesting question!