# The converse of the Heine–Borel property

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

I have been reading on the **Heine–Borel theorem** and **Heine–Borel property** and their relation to topological vector spaces.

The **Heine–Borel theorem** states each subset of Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^n$, is closed and bounded if and only if it is compact.

A topological vector space is said to have the **Heine–Borel property** if each closed and bounded set in is compact.

From this I understand that not every TVS has the Heine–Borel property. However, what about the converse? i.e, Is each compact subset of TVS, closed and bounded?

Comment: You have to be careful how exactly you define bounded without the use of a norm

Comment: @EvangelopoulosF., In our textbook, a subset $A$ of a TVS is bounded if for all nbd $V$ of $0$ there exists $\lambda>0$ such that $A\subseteq \lambda V$ .

Answer (score 1):

In a topological vector space, one point sets (which are clearly compact) are closed if and only if the space is Hausdorff (see, for example, Rudin's book on functional analysis). In a Hausdorff space, every compact set is closed.

If $C$ is compact and $V$ an open neighborhood of $0$, the family of sets of the form $nV$ is an open cover of $C$. If a finite subcover exists, there must exist a cover given by a single such $n V$, so every compact set in a topological vector space is bounded.

Comment: I understand the second part, but how does every one point set is compact and closed imply every set is every compact set is closed?

Comment: @gbd It does not. The point is that in a TVS, every compact set is closed if and only if the TVS has the Hausdorff property.

Comment: What I mean is if we assume that a TVS has Hausdorff property, then I know that every singleton is closed and compact (we use Rudin's book). However, I don't understand how that implies every compact set is closed.

Comment: In a Hausdorff space every compact set is [closed](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83355/how-to-prove-that-a-compact-set-in-a-hausdorff-topological-space-is-closed)

Comment: Does every finite-dimensional topological vector space has the Heine–Borel property?

Comment: Yes; if they are Hausdorff, they are linearly homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the usual topology. If they are not Hausdorff, they have a quotient that is. But this is a different question.