# Spaces where each compact subset has compact closure: have they already been studied?

Tags: general-topology, soft-question, compactness, descriptive-set-theory, separation-axioms

Let $(X, \tau) $ be a topological space be such that for every $K\subset X$ compact implies $\operatorname{cl}(K)$ is also compact.

I am interested in the study of such spaces [call $\textrm{G} $ space, if there is no name].

Let's start with few examples:

1. **Hausdorff spaces**: [In a Hausdorff space a compact set is closed](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/83355/977780), hence it's a $\textrm{G}$ space.
2. **KC space** (A topological space in which compact sets are closed) gives a large class of examples of $\textrm{G}$ space.

All Hausdorff spaces are KC spaces and there are examples of non Hausdorff KC spaces [Co-countable topology on uncountable set].

3. **Non KC but still $\textrm{G}$ space**: Co-finite topology on an infinite set.
4. **Non $\textrm{G}$ space** :
   Particular point topology on an infinite set. Let $X$ be any set and $p\in X.$ Then define $\tau_p=\{U\subset X : p\in U\}\cup\{\emptyset\}.$ In $(X, \tau_p) $ the set $K=\{p\}$ is compact but $\operatorname{cl}(K) =X$ is not compact.

Hausdorff space $\subset $ KC space $\subset \textrm{ G}$  space

> Is the study of such topological spaces already done?

Comment: Each finite space is G. This gives a lot of non-T1 examples. (Note that KC spaces are T1.)

Comment: @Ulli Both are obvious. A finite set is always compact but it is not closed unless the space is $T_1$ .For the second claim :$\{x\}$ is compact $\implies$ closed in KC space $\implies$ $T_1$

Comment: Well, I didn't say that it's not obvious. (Probably as obvious as that KC spaces are G.) But it indicates that you cannot expect too much nice properties within the class of G spaces.

Comment: In example four, is this not just the discrete topology? so shouldn't $\{x\}$ also be closed and thus $cl(\{x\})=\{x\}$? sorry if I am missing something

Comment: @chris No. The topology $\tau_p$ is not discrete. It's known as particular point topology ( discrete iff $X$ is singleton) .Infact $\textrm{cl}(\{x\})=\begin{cases} \{x\} &x\neq p\\X&x=p\end{cases}$

Comment: @QuitMSE thank you, for the clarification